# javascript parent and child window

Tags: javascript, parent-child

I have a page that uses javascript and opens a child window which updates some fields in the parent window.

Now the fields that are updated have a `onchange()` function I want the child window to call this function when updating the field.

Is this possible using javascript?

***EDIT:***

My Code:

This is the link that opens the child window:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" style="width:100%; height:125%" onclick="window.open('otherExpenses.php','Ratting','width=350,height=550,left=50,top=50,toolbar=1,status=1,');">Open Child</a>
```

And in the child window, some operations are done with user interaction, then this is how the child is closed:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="post_value()">Close Child</a>
```

And the `post_value()` function:

```
function post_value()
{
    opener.document.overHeads.overheadOther.value = document.otherExpenses.TextBox27.value;
    opener.document.overHeads.hiddenOther.value = document.otherExpenses.TextBox27.value;
    //here I want to call a function from the parent window that updates some field in the parent window.
    self.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to answer your question: "Is this possible using javascript?"

## yes

you'll need to post some more code if you want a better answer.

If the function belongs to the parent window, you have to attach it to the child window from the context of the parent window:

```
//w is the child window
w.document.getElementById('theId').onchange(window.somefunction);
```

Comment: I have added code to my question, hope it helps understanding my question.

Comment: HTML belongs in .html files, CSS belongs in .css files, JavaScript belongs in .js files. It's good form not to fill your HTML with JavaScript.  The issue is that you're losing your reference to the child window when you call it from the link.

Comment: Thanks, you directed me the path and I figured out the rest